# Vim disable autofold when I scroll down?

Tags: vim, folding

I have folding enabled in vim, here is .vimrc snipet.

```
set foldmethod=syntax
set foldnestmax=1
set foldlevel=0
set foldclose=all
```

It works fine, but when I scroll down a c-function it automatically folds, any idea on how to leave the fold open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim is just doing what you've instructed it to do; especially with your chosen combination of `'foldclose'` and `'foldlevel'`. From `:help 'foldclose'`:

```
'foldclose' 'fcl'   string (default "")
        When set to "all", a fold is closed when the cursor isn't in it and
        its level is higher than 'foldlevel'.  Useful if you want folds to
        automatically close when moving out of them.
```

Simply drop the `set foldclose=all` if you don't like that behavior.